# Count number of list items with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone have a look at my code and tell me what the problem is?

I am trying to build a jquery function that counts all list item elements that contains a specific text.
The bit where it should count all "li"s works:

$(allLip).text(allLi.length);

but the function where is is supposed to count all "li"s with a specific text doesn't work.

Is there any way that I can achieve this with pure JS?

Thanks in advance.

```js
var allLi = $("#lists ol li");
    
    var allLip = $("#all-li");
    var numP = $("#num-p");
    var numS = $("#num-s");
    var numP12 = $("#num-p-12");
    
    
    var pText = "(p)";
    var sText = "(s)";
    var p12Text = "(p-12)"
    
    
    
    
    
    $(allLip).text(allLi.length);
    
    $(allLi).each(function(){
        var pCounter = 0;
        var sCounter = 0;
        var p12Counter = 0;
        
        if($(allLi).has(pText)){
            pCounter++;
            $(numP).text(pCounter);
        }
        if($(allLi).has(sText)){
            sCounter++;
            $(numS).text(sCounter);
        }
        if($(allLi).has(p12Text)){
            p12Counter++;
            $(numP12).text(p12Counter);
        }
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lists">
    
    <ol>
        <li>list 1 - (p)</li>
        <li>list 2 - (s)</li>
        <li>list 3 - (p-12)</li>
        <li>list 4 - (p)</li>
        <li>list 5 - (p)</li>
        <li>list 6 - (s)</li>
        <li>list 7 - (p-12)</li>
        <li>list 8 - (p-12)</li>
    </ol>
    
</div>




<!-- How many "li" -->
<p id="all-li"></p>

<!-- How many "li" with "(p)" text-->
<p id="num-p"></p>

<!-- How many "li" with "(s)" text-->
<p id="num-s"></p>

<!-- How many "li" with "(p-12)" text-->
<p id="num-p-12"></p>
```

Comment: Do like `$(allLi).text().match(new RegExp(pText))` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for a loop, you can simply use jQuery [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector with [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter) method.

```js
var allLi = $("#lists ol li");
var allLip = $("#all-li");
var numP = $("#num-p");
var numS = $("#num-s");
var numP12 = $("#num-p-12");


var pText = "(p)";
var sText = "(s)";
var p12Text = "(p-12)"





allLip.text(allLi.length);
numP.text(allLi.filter(':contains("' + pText + '")').length);
numS.text(allLi.filter(':contains("' + sText + '")').length);
numP12.text(allLi.filter(':contains("' + p12Text + '")').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lists">
  <ol>
    <li>list 1 - (p)</li>
    <li>list 2 - (s)</li>
    <li>list 3 - (p-12)</li>
    <li>list 4 - (p)</li>
    <li>list 5 - (p)</li>
    <li>list 6 - (s)</li>
    <li>list 7 - (p-12)</li>
    <li>list 8 - (p-12)</li>
  </ol>
</div>




<!-- How many "li" -->
<p id="all-li"></p>
<!-- How many "li" with "(p)" text-->
<p id="num-p"></p>
<!-- How many "li" with "(s)" text-->
<p id="num-s"></p>
<!-- How many "li" with "(p-12)" text-->
<p id="num-p-12"></p>
```

Comment: Clear and easy. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

When you are looping thru the items, you need to pass the current element in the loop and evaluate it (you are currently evaluating all the items in every loop)

See demo below:

```js
var allLi = $("#lists ol li");

var allLip = $("#all-li");
var numP = $("#num-p");
var numS = $("#num-s");
var numP12 = $("#num-p-12");
var pText = "(p)";
var sText = "(s)";
var p12Text = "(p-12)"

// get all LI elements
$(allLip).text(allLi.length);

// init counters
var pCounter = 0;
var sCounter = 0;
var p12Counter = 0;

// loop thru LI items
$(allLi).each(function(idx, liItem) {
  // if the item has the pText, count it
  if ($(liItem).text().indexOf(pText) != -1) {
    pCounter++;
  }

  // if the item has the sText, count it
  if ($(liItem).text().indexOf(sText) != -1) {
    sCounter++;
  }
  
  // if the item has the p12Text, count it
  if ($(liItem).text().indexOf(p12Text) != -1) {
    p12Counter++;
  }
});

// display results
$(numP).text(pCounter);
$(numP12).text(p12Counter);
$(numS).text(sCounter);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lists">
  <ol>
    <li>list 1 - (p)</li>
    <li>list 2 - (s)</li>
    <li>list 3 - (p-12)</li>
    <li>list 4 - (p)</li>
    <li>list 5 - (p)</li>
    <li>list 6 - (s)</li>
    <li>list 7 - (p-12)</li>
    <li>list 8 - (p-12)</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<!-- How many "li" -->
LIs: <span id="all-li"></span>
<br/>

<!-- How many "li" with "(p)" text-->
LIs w/P: <span id="num-p"></span>
<br/>

<!-- How many "li" with "(s)" text-->
LIs w/S: <span id="num-s"></span>
<br/>

<!-- How many "li" with "(p-12)" text-->
LIs w/P-12: <span id="num-p-12"></span>
```

Comment: I think I might have used the filter method followed by .length

Comment: @Jtbs Yes, it's a better approach... I just used the loop to keep in line with the OPs original code... (it might be easier to integrate to the existing code, if such a thing were important to OP)

Comment: I think your answer requires less processing than the filter method, but it would take a lot of list items to make a noticeable difference to the user.

Comment: @Jtbs I meant your suggestion is a better approach (not my answer) :)

Comment: yep, I was just letting you know that your answer isn't a bad approach. It has some benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this one will help you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var allLip = $("#all-li");
    var numP = $("#num-p");
    var numS = $("#num-s");
    var numP12 = $("#num-p-12");

    var pText = "(p)";
    var sText = "(s)";
    var p12Text = "(p-12)"
    var allLi = 'li';


    $(allLip).text($(allLi).length);
    var pCounter = 0;
    var sCounter = 0;
    var p12Counter = 0;
    var params = [pCounter, sCounter, p12Counter];
    $(allLi).each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':contains("' + pText + '")')) {
            params[0]++;
        }
        if ($(this).is(':contains("' + sText + '")')) {
            params[1]++;
        }
        if ($(this).is(':contains("' + p12Text + '")')) {
            params[2]++;
        }

    }, params);
    $(numP).text(params[0]);
    $(numS).text(params[1]);
    $(numP12).text(params[2]);

});
```